# Prove that $[0,1]$ is uncountable by proving that Player 2 has a wining strategy

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am self studying point set topology with [MAT327](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/biglist.pdf) from Toronto University. In the topic of countability (chapter 4), the following problem

Let $A\subseteq[0,1]$ be a fixed subset.

Let $A_0 = (0,1) = (a_0,b_0)$.
In their turn, Player 1 chooses $a_n\in (a_{n-1},b_{n-1})$ and Player 2 chooses $b_n\in(a_n,b_{n-1})$. This generates a sequence of nested subsets $A_n=(a_n,b_n)$. The sequence $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$ is monotonic and bounded from above, thus $a_n\rightarrow a\in(0,1)$

Player 1 wins if $a\in A$, Player 2 wins otherwise. Prove that if $A$ is countable, then Player 2 has a winning strategy.

I understand the result intuitively: If $A$ is countable there will be "holes" in $A$. I don't know where can I start building such strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint - if $A$ is countable, player $2$ can use each round to make sure that one element of $A$ will not be the final limit point, and after countably many steps, he can make sure that no element in $A$ is the final limit point.

Let's choose an enumeration of the countable set $A$ - $(q_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

In the first round, player $1$ chooses some $a_1$ and now I am given the interval $(a_1,1)$.

I want to make sure that $q_1$ is not the limit point. So I can choose some $b_1$ so that $b_1<q_1$ (this can be done unless $q_1=0$, but this case is easy to fix).

Now my new interval is $(a_1,b_1)$, and immediately $q_1$ will not be the limit point, since it is strictly outside of my new interval (not even at the boundary). Player $1$ now chooses some $a_2\in (a_1,b_1)$ and we continue.

What should I do next?

Comment: Very clever! Now I would repeat this procedure with $q_2\in (a_1,b_1)$. At every step there are at most a countable amount of points of A in this interval, so one can reenumerate them in such a way that $q_n$ in the interval for the step n. Given a specific example let A be the set of rational numbers in $(0,1)$, given any number $x$ on this set, there will be an n s.t. $a_n>x$ or $b_n<x$. In particular one can choose $b_n$ as the average of $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$